# mongodb nodejs - converting circular structure

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I have some code that pulls all documents from a collection and puts it onto a webpage. a simplified version looks like this:

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb"),
    express = require("express"),
    mongoServer = new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017),
    dbConnector = new mongodb.Db('systemMonitor', mongoServer),
    db;

var app = new express();

app.get('/drives', function(req, res) {
  db.collection('driveInfo', function(err, collection) {
    if (err) throw err;
    collection.find({}, function(err, documents) {
      res.send(documents);
    });
  });
});

dbConnector.open(function(err, opendb) {
  if (err) throw err;
  db = opendb;
  app.listen(80);
});
```

I have a driveInfo collection which contains a long list of documents. Each document contains nested objects. What I would like to do, is whenever someone visits /drives in their browser, to print the entire collection as a json object so that I can grab everything with jquery later (beginnings of an api)

However, I get an error saying "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON". The error on the page points to this line of code:

```
collection.find({}, function(err, documents) {
  res.send(documents);
});
```

I'm unsure what the problem is, or where the self-reference is. Am I not querying the collection properly?

Comment: Have you tried logging the output of the query?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not sure what version of the API you are using, but i think that your syntax might be wrong looking at the API spec:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

This is the declaration:

```
db.collection.find(<criteria>, <projection>)
```

And you are definitely misusing the projection parameter. Passing a callback like you are doing seems to return the **db** object in the result, which is causing the circular error during JSON serialization in express.

The correct code for the find all operation should be something like:

```
collection.find({}).toArray(function(error, documents) {
    if (err) throw error;

    res.send(documents);
});
```

Comment: ah yes, I pulled the original code from another stackoverflow answer which I guess was incorrect syntactically. The one you provided works though, thanks!

Comment: You are welcome ;).. this kind of stuff happens of often with Node.js since the API's are not stable.

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was getting the error because I was querying(using mongoose find method) without doing an await. Please see below

**Query that gave the error (as I haven't executed this query using await)** :

```
const tours = Tour.find({
    startLocation: {
      $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[longitude, latitude], radius] }
    }
  });
```

Error that I got on postman due to this :

```
"message": "Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'\n    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'\n    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'\n    --- property 'topology' closes the circle"
```

**How I got rid of the above error (added **await**) :**

```
 const tours = await Tour.find({
        startLocation: {
          $geoWithin: { $centerSphere: [[longitude, latitude], radius] }
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

**callback option is from Mongoose** not from MongoDB [see docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

```
// Mongoose Docs : callback option
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }}, function (err, docs) {});


// Example
app.get( '/api/users' , (req,res,done)=>{
  let getUsers = NewUser.find({},(err,data)=>{
    if(err) return done(err);
    res.json(data)
  });
});
```

Look that the response is into callback that in your case it would be

```
YourModel.find({}, function(err, documents) {
  if(err) return done(err);
  res.send(documents);  //  <-- here
});
// <-- not here
```

In Mongo there is a *cursor method* to access the documents `next()` [see docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#mongodb-method-db.collection.find) :

```
var myCursor = db.bios.find( );
var myDocument = myCursor.hasNext() ? myCursor.next() : null;
if (myDocument) {
    var myName = myDocument.name;
    print (tojson(myName));
}
```

---

You can find CRUD operations in mongo docs at [manual/crud](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/). In [Query Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) you will see `db.inventory.find( {} )` : To select all documents in the collection, pass an empty document as the query filter parameter to the find method.

---

Async/Await function solution : [Mongo Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)

```
app.get( '/api/users' , async (req,res)=>{
  const getUsers = await NewUser.find({});
  res.json( getUsers );
})
```

< callback > solution : [Mongoose Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find).

```
app.get( '/api/users' , (req,res,done)=>{
  let getUsers = NewUser.find({},(err,data)=>{
    if(err) return done(err);
    res.json(data)
  });
});
```

---

Answer (score 0):

`const res1 = await db.collection("some-db").find()`

Here, res1 will contain a "cursor" which has a circular structure, hence the given error is thrown.

Try adding `const res2 = await res1.toArray()` to the code.

Here, `res2` will now contain an array of documents, pointed by cursor `res1`, which is the documents you were querying for.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to await the `.find()` method and was sending an unresolved promise back in the response.

Changed this:

```
const posts = Post.find({});
```

to this:

```
const posts = await Post.find({});
```