# mongodb Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I run the next command from the console and it returns ordinal object, nothing special:

```
>> db.query.find({"user_id":"111"})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58bbf5bf17cc9100046bdff"), "query" : "my query", "user_id" : "111", "links" : [ ] }
```

But the next code (run for the same `user_id`) fails on `JSON.stringify(results)` with `Converting circular structure to JSON`:

```
var args = {'user_id': userId};
console.log("database: query.find(%s)", JSON.stringify(args));
db.collection('query').find(args, function(err, results){
    if(err) {
        console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
    } 
    console.log("results:", JSON.stringify(results));
});
```

Why?

Comment: you have ObjectId in your result..JSON conversion fails to convert ObjectId

Comment: @BibekSubedi it's auto-generated by the mongo itself.. could you propose some solution? (but i don't want to generate id by myself or use some mongo wrapper)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144236/how-to-convert-a-mongodb-document-to-json-object this might help

Comment: Do you use mongoose or anything? Then perhaps you should try to add `.lean()`. As described by the mongoose docs, documents returned from queries with the lean option true are plain javascript objects, not Mongoose Documents.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer here: [mongodb nodejs - converting circular structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715859/mongodb-nodejs-converting-circular-structure)

I've just added `toArray`:

`db.collection('query').find(args).toArray(function(err, results){`